# Object starts moving along collider edge if the angle is too great

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not sure what is causing this, but I have objects that when they hit a collider at too much of an angle (obtuse angle), they don't bounce off it, they just start moving along the `x` or the `y` depending on if it hits the top or side.

I am using the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        // Set the start direction
        direction = new Vector2(Random.value, Random.value);
        rb.velocity = direction * speed;
    }
    void LateUpdate(){
        rb.velocity = speed * rb.velocity.normalized;
    }
}
```

I then have on the moving object a `CircleCollider2d` collider with a `2D physics material` with the following values: `Friction = 0` and `Bounciness = 1`

Here are the settings I have on the ball:

[image: Ball Settings]

What can I do to stop the item from wall riding?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, but more complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem, it will be hard to provide any suggestions. That said, why are you recomputing `velocity`? With your given `Friction` and `Bounciness` values, should not the `velocity` magnitude remain constant anyway? I would not be surprised if normalizing and recomputing the `velocity` vector is directly causing your problem, due to some underflow happening somewhere in the calculations.

Comment: That is minimal, I don't have anything else

Comment: Really? Where is the declaration of `rb` in your example? Where is the rest of the information that would allow someone to easily create the exact objects in their project that you have in yours? Take a moment to consider what a person would need to do in order to reproduce the behavior you describe, and note all of the missing information that would be required to unambiguously understand your scenario. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how and why to provide a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example.

Comment: I commented out `LateUpdate` and that had no effect, the issue remained.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

The issue was not with the code, but in the Physics2D settings.

I needed to lower `Velocity Threshold` to a smaller number.